# How to import c++ dll printf to c# textbox

Tags: c#, c++, printf, dllimport

I wish to make the C++ DLL communicate with the C# codes, but I cannot get it to work, I have to import the "printf" Messages from the C++ DLL to print in a C# Textbox, can anyone help me on this as long as it works it is fine for me can some one guide me? My Main priority is that the C# will be able to print the "printf" functions in the C++ DLL
The C++ DLL Codes but the codes is compiled as C:

```
ReceiverInformation()
{
     //Initialize Winsock version 2.2
     if( WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0)
     {
          printf("Server: WSAStartup failed with error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
          return -1;
     }
     else
     {
         printf("Server: The Winsock DLL status is %s.\n", wsaData.szSystemStatus);
         // Create a new socket to receive datagrams on.
         ReceivingSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

         if (ReceivingSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
         {
              printf("Server: Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
              // Clean up
              WSACleanup();
              // Exit with error
              return -1;
         }
         else
         {
              printf("Server: socket() is OK!\n");
         }
     }
}
```

And this is the C# codes, I tried to import the C++ DLL can someone point out what I should do with sample codes made from my codes:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport(@"C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Server_Receiver Solution DLL\Debug\Server_Receiver.dll", EntryPoint = "DllMain")]
        private static extern int ReceiverInformation();

        private static int ReceiverInformation(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //textBox1.Text = "Hello";
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }           
    }
```

Comment: Consider using C++/CLI for this sort of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `printf`. Pass your string to C#. Like this:

C++ DLL code snippet follows:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Test(char* message, int length)
{
    _snprintf(message, length, "Test");
    return 1;
}
```

C# snippet follows:

```
[DllImport(@"test.dll")]
private static extern int Test(StringBuilder sb, int capacity);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(32);
    Test(sb, sb.Capacity);

    // Do what you need here. In your case, testBox1.Text = sb.ToString()
    Console.WriteLine(sb);
}
```

Make sure that your `StringBuilder`'s capacity can fit any message you output from your DLL export. Otherwise, it will be truncated.